# Uploading multiple images using SRWebClient in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use [Swift-SRWebClient](https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient)  http client framework  for uploading images to a Restful API. I am using below method to upload the image.

```
var image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "apple.jpeg")
let imageData:NSData = NSData.dataWithData(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0))
SRWebClient.POST("http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/upload/upload.php")
    .data(imageData, fieldName:"file", data:["days":"1","title":"Swift-SRWebClient","caption":"Uploaded via Swift-SRWebClient (https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient)"])
    .send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
        //process success response
    },failure:{(error:NSError!) -> Void in
        //process failure response
    })
```

This method allows me to upload only **single** image.

Please help me to understand how can I upload an array of images or multiple images in a single POST.

Comment: I see on line 149 of the [source](https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient/blob/master/SRWebClient/SRWebClient.swift) that this library's `.data` method only takes **one** image as an argument.

Comment: yes that right... How can I modify it to accept multiple images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your replies. I fond the solution by modifying [this file](https://github.com/sraj/Swift-SRWebClient/blob/master/SRWebClient/SRWebClient.swift) and adding the following changes in it.

```
 /**
    *  Function to upload image & data using POST request
    *
    *  @param image:NSData       image data of type NSData
    *  @param fieldName:String   field name for uploading image
    *  @param data:RequestData?  optional value of type Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    *
    *  @return self instance to support function chaining
    */
    public func data(image:[NSData], fieldName:String, data:RequestData?) -> SRWebClient {

            let uniqueId = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString

            var postBody:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
            var postData:String = String()
            var boundary:String = "------WebKitFormBoundary\(uniqueId)"

            self.urlRequest?.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")

            if(data != nil && data!.count > 0) {
                postData += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
                for (key, value : AnyObject) in data! {
                    if let value = value as? String {
                        postData += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
                        postData += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n"
                        postData += "\(value)\r\n"
                    }
                }
            }

        for i in image{
            postData += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
            postData += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(fieldName)\"; filename=\"\(Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970*1000)).jpg\"\r\n"
            postData += "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"
            postBody.appendData(postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            postBody.appendData(i)
            postData = String()
            postData += "\r\n"
            postData += "\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n"
            postBody.appendData(postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        }


            self.urlRequest!.HTTPBody = NSData(data: postBody)

        return self
    }
```

Now I am able to add multiple images using the SRWebClient...